# How do you correctly instantiate and show a view programmatically in a Single View Application for the iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I would like to know how to correctly show a view programmatically. I will try to explain what i did so far:

The application has a storyboard with two view controllers. One of them has an identifier: " detailview". When i click on a button on the initial view controller i want to show the view controller with the identifier "detailview". Currently i'm using this code:

```
TI4ViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailview"];
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;                     
[window addSubview:vc.view];
```

This works fine to show the view "detailview". But when i add a button on the detailview controller and add a touchdown event in the TI4ViewController(the view controller that's connected to "detailview") i'm getting an exception while clicking on this button.

I'm getting the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[__NSCFType TestDown:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e0f670'

I'm using Xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I think the ViewController is released, but i'm not sure.

Comment: How did you hook up the button in detailView? What method does it invoke?

Comment: Just by dragging from the buttons OnTouchDown event/action to TI4ViewController.h

Comment: What do you want the button to do? Usually you should have a method starting with IBAction and link the button to that, not the viewController itself.

Comment: I've linked the button to an empty method starting with IBAction. It's an empty button, but the exception is already raised before it's called. I've checked this. So i think that the view controller is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I should have added the TI4ViewController as property of the initial view controller. Now it's removed from memory when you leave the function.

Comment: If this is the answer to the question then please mark it as correct.

Comment: You can only mark your own answers as correct after two days.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding another view you can use segue. You can find an example [here](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/using-storyboards-to-create-a-single-view-application/1363/)

Comment: Sorry can't use seque. I want to programmatically show views. The reason for this is that i want to show views in one view together with a verticaltabbar.

Comment: you can still use segue's programmatically.